# Swift how to use 'self' as generics

Tags: swift

I have a class 
`ManagedObject:NSManagedObject`

and some subclass

```
MOProject:ManagedObject
MOOrganization:ManagedObject
```

and so on

and in the ManagedObject

```
request(Router.Create(object: userInfo)).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let result):
        Mapper<self>().map(result)
        completion(result: Result(success:"dd"))
    case .Failure( _):
        completion(result: Result(failure: Error.CacheNotExist))
    }
})
```

`Mapper<self>().map(result)` is error 
I just want is as `T:ManagedObject`

if I init MOProject I want 
`Mapper< MOProject >().map(result)`

if I init MOOrganization I want 
`Mapper< MOOrganization >().map(result)`

Comment: If you want to use the `Self` type, then you must capitalize it. `self` is a Property. From the docs: "“Every instance of a type has an implicit property called self, which is exactly equivalent to the instance itself. You use the self property to refer to the current instance within its own instance methods.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to specialize a generic type based on dynamic information. Swift doesn't do that, at least not without help.

What you can put in the angle brackets that go with a generic type is different depending on where you're using it. If you're *defining a new* generic type (like `class Foo<T>` or `func bar<T>(t: T)`), the angle brackets contain *type parameters* — those are like variables you can use within the type definition. If you're *using* a generic type (like `var a: Foo<Int>` or calling `bar("some string")`, which implicitly a call to `bar<String>`, the angle brackets have to contain *valid type names*. In other words, the definition of a generic type is the place where it's generic, and the use site is the place where it's specialized.

Furthermore, specialization can only happen at compile time. What you put in the angle brackets when using a generic type has to be a type name known to the compiler, not an expression that produces something only at run time.

So your problem with trying to call a class method on `Mapper<self>` is twofold: first, `self` is not a type name, and second, you want the place where you're putting `self` to contain something dynamic.

You can still conditionally create a `Mapper<MOProject>` or a `Mapper<MOOrganization>` based on the runtime type of `self` — you just have to do that dispatch yourself so that you can provide static types to the compiler. The simplest (if not most elegant) way to do that might be to switch on the type:

```
//...
case .Success(let result):
    switch self {
        case is MOProject:
            Mapper<MOProject>().map(result)
            completion(result: Result(success:"dd"))
        case is MOOrganization:
            Mapper<MOOrganization>().map(result)
            completion(result: Result(success:"dd"))
    }
case .Failure( _):
    //...
```

(Warning: coded in SE mobile app, untested. But something along these lines *should* work...)

Comment: Thank you very much,I have  solved id similar to you.
and thank you let me know why it is does't work

Answer (score 0):

Based on your usage I assume you want to use `Self` not `self` in your expression. The first is a type, the second is a property.

> “Every instance of a type has an implicit property called self, which is exactly equivalent to the instance itself. You use the self property to refer to the current instance within its own instance methods.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).” iBooks.

However, I'm not sure it'll work to use Self where you are attempting to use it. I'm having trouble finding documentation on Self. You'll often see it in protocol definitions. I don't know if it's legal in the context of a struct or class.

UPDATE: I just tried to use `Self` in a class and got a compiler error: "`Self` is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class;"

If you provide more context of the method where you are using Mapper I could maybe suggest a fix. Do you have a generic type variable you can use in that context?

Comment: ```
if I init MOProject I want 
`Mapper< MOProject >().map(result)`

if I init MOOrganization I want 
`Mapper< MOOrganization >().map(result)`
```

Comment: Understood. I don't have an answer for you off the top of my head. You may have to restructure your code somewhat, but I don't have a good suggestion.

Comment: It's not an uncommon issue. I've seen similar issues before. I'm just not finding any good guidance at the time.